# Group by field in Grafana Table

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

I have some data in an Elasticsearch table, which looks a lot like this

```
{ "product": "apple",  duration: "10",

  "product": "orange", duration: "50" }` ...etc
```

Is there a way to build a Grafana table which shows aggregations, but automatically groups each table row by "product" ?

I'm currently building each row manually, with a separate query "`series:"fruit_processing.performance" AND product:"apple"`" for each product, and setting the table as a Time Series Aggregation, but this solution doesn't seems scalable as we add more and more "fruits".

Is this possible ? Thanks in advance!

[image]